# how to calc retention for two different event with different properties?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I use clickhouse to calc user retention for below two event:

1. login: with properties "os" which can be "android" or "ios".
2. payment: with no properties of "os".

data examples:

```
uid      date       event   os

('user1', 2023-12-15, 'login', 'ios')
('user1', 2023-12-16, 'login', 'android')
('user1', 2023-12-16, 'payment' '')
```

now I want to calc the retention group by "os". I want to know, how many people pay from ios, and how many pay from android. How to do this?

bad sql example:

```
select client, uid, retention(date='xxx' and event = 'login', ......) 
from data 
group by os, uid;
```

this sql doesn't work, because it first `group by` os and then send to `retention()`. When groups, it divide the data into 3 part and then call `retention()`, the result is wrong.

expected result:

```
ios     | user1 | [1, 0, 1]   // for ios group, user retention at second day.

android | user1 | [1, 1, 0]   // for android group, user retention at first day.
```

I want the sql to archive the following function like this:

when I group by os, it treats 'ios' and '' the same group and treats 'android' and '' the same group (because the 'payment' event doesn't have the 'os' property). The group result then send to `retention()` will get the right answer.

Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: Please edit your question and share the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Try below SQL query, where I attributed '`payment`' events to the OS of a user's last '`login`' event using a window function, and then calculated user retention grouped by this attributed OS.

```
WITH lastLoginOS AS (
    SELECT 
        uid, 
        maxIf(os, event = 'login') OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as last_os
    FROM data
    WHERE event IN ('login', 'payment')
)
SELECT 
    if(event = 'payment', last_os, os) as os_grouped,
    uid,
    countIf(event = 'payment', date = '2023-12-16') as retention_day1,
    countIf(event = 'payment', date = '2023-12-17') as retention_day2,
    countIf(event = 'payment', date = '2023-12-18') as retention_day3
FROM lastLoginOS
GROUP BY os_grouped, uid;
```

**Using retention()**

```
SELECT 
    cohort,
    retention(
        toDate(first_login_date), 
        toDate(event_date), 
        1,  -- defines the period for retention, e.g., 1 day
        uid, 
        event = 'payment'
    ) as retention_rate
FROM (
    SELECT 
        uid,
        minIf(date, event = 'login') as first_login_date,
        date as event_date,
        event
    FROM data
    WHERE event IN ('login', 'payment')
    GROUP BY uid, event_date, event
)
GROUP BY cohort
```

Comment: Can't I use the retention() function any more?

Comment: You can use the retention() function, for that you would need to define cohorts based on a specific event (like a user's first login or first payment) and then track subsequent events (like subsequent logins or payments) over time. I added retention as well